# C# VSTO SaveCopyAs checked-in presentation/document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, vsto, ms-office

I have created a VSTO add-in for MS-Office in C#.Net, and that can export all the slides/pages as images.

But I am unable to export the slides/pages if the presentation/document is opened from [remote SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-and-share-a-presentation-using-sharepoint-4306e7dd-8989-4864-bfaa-a653174ffc35) and the presentation/document required to [checked-out before they can be edited](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/set-up-a-library-to-require-check-out-of-files-0c73792b-f727-4e19-a1f9-3173899e695b). However, I don't want to change/update anything in the remote file, I just want to make a copy of that file into "temp" folder so that it can be used to export the slides/pages as images.

I am using following code to create a temporary copy of the presentation

```
Presentation vstoPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
var filename = vstoPresentation.Name;
var tempPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp");
string temp_file = tempPath + "\\" + filename;
vstoPresentation.SaveCopyAs(temp_file);
```

I am getting follwoing error

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80048240): Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Presentation cannot be modified.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation.SaveCopyAs(String FileName, PpSaveAsFileType FileFormat, MsoTriState EmbedTrueTypeFonts)
   at PowerPointExport.ThisAddIn.ExportImages() in F:\Path\to\project\PowerPointExport\ThisAddIn.cs:line 271
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual string passed to the `SaveCopyAs` method?

Comment: Did you try to use the `SaveAs` method instead?

Comment: Yes, I tried the SaveAs() method also but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the actual string which is passed to the `SaveCopyAs` method looks like...

As a workaround, you may try to use [Presentation.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.saveas) method which saves a presentation that's never been saved, or *saves a previously saved presentation under a different name*.

Comment: I am passing the "C:\Users\freedom\AppData\Local\Temp\welcome-inspire.pptx" in SaveCopyAs() function

Comment: Was the presentation opened under the protected mode?

Comment: you can say that because powerpoint forces me to check out the presentation before any change can be done, but I don't want to do any changes just want to create a copy. However, if I go to FIle > SaveAs menu then I can save the presentation but it must be done by C# code.